# Firebase how to use orderbychild

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

medics/randomid/medicname = someValue

I want this medic name get listview with firebase

```
dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(kullaniciuid).child(medic).orderByChild("medicname");

dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


        ss = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        s = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        list.add(ss);

        barkodlist.add(s);

        count++;
        if(count >= dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()){
            //stop progress bar here
            count = 0;
            adapter();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's or question or problem? It's not quite clear from the title or post.

Answer (score 1):

If your database looks like:

```
medics:
    <RANDOM_UUID>:
        medicname: "Some value"
```

Then you should query using

```
dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("medics").orderByChild("medicname");
dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { ... });
```

Ignore the UUID if you're querying childs using `orderByChild`.

Comment: ss = dataSnapshot.child("medicname").getValue().toString(); I used this code and I solved