# How to filter and retrieve nested child in Firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is a simplified version of the DB structure that I'm working with:

```
  "user" : {
    "nhbAQ9p8BrMoAIbJNKvLlXTdiNz2" : {
      "log" : {
        "-LhMVugmjmIdqwrJSURp" : {
          "a" : 25120,
          "timeStamp" : 1560312000000,
        },
        "-Lh_Z9GsJJvlMOpVV9jU" : {
          "a" : 19033,
          "timeStamp" : 1564718400000,
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm having issues filtering and retrieving the value of "a" with a given user id (e.g. nhbAQ9p8BrMoAIbJNKvLlXTdiNz2) and timeStamp (e.g.1560312000000).

I've tried combinations of `orderByChild()`, `equalTo()`, and adding a `once()` listener to do the task but they've only returned `null` so far.

The code that I have:

```
firebase.database().ref('user/' + userID + + '/log').orderByChild('timeStamp').equalTo(targetTimeStamp).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    let userLog = snapshot.val().a
})
```

where `userID` is a string and `targetTimeStamp` is a number.

I checked the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data) and a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47803870/firebase-how-to-use-orderbychild) about `orderByChild()` but I'm still not sure what is causing it to return `null`.

This is my first time posting a question, please comment if there's anyway I can make this clearer and any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where `userID` and `targetTimeStamp` are both strings.

That is the reason nothing is returned. In the database the values of the `timeStamp` property is a number, and comparing a number to a string never returns a match.

To make the query work, convert the string to a number:

```
...equalTo(parseInt(targetTimeStamp)).once(...
```

Aside from that a query against the Firebase Database may potentially have multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So you need to handle that case too:

```
firebase.database().ref('user/' + userID + + '/log').orderByChild('timeStamp').equalTo(targetTimeStamp).once('value').then(function(results){
    results.forEach(function(snapshot) {
        let userLog = snapshot.val().a
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just loaded up the changes with `parseInt` but it still returns `null`.

Comment: I added an example showing another mistake. If that still doesn't allow you to fix the problem, can you provide a link to a jsbin (or similar site) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the followup. I added the `results.forEach(function(snapshot)` block but the lines inside were never executed. I haven't used jsbin before please allow me some time to set it up.

Comment: I was setting up the jsbin and decided to give a final look at the code. I realized that it was missing one digit for my input timeStamp because I forgot that for some reason Firebase's database display always hides one character for all values on my desktop display. It works now after the edit. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great to hear that you found the cause of the problem Nariety. This is one of the great things about creating an MCVE: you often find your own typos. :)